# Reinstall new linux distro on existing partition without effecting other partitions and GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2, dual-boot, grub-legacy

So, for my studies I got a computer with Windows and Ubuntu. A couple of days ago i tried to change the desktop environment of Ubuntu and kind of broke it hard somehow. Now, I'd like to remove Ubuntu and install a new Linux distro.
The problem is that I have GRUB on my computer and I do need my Windows machine to remain. My question is:
**How do I remove Ubuntu and install a new Linux distro without effecting GRUB or Windows?**

Comment: Is your ubuntu on a seperate partition to your windows os?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Tho I can send you a picture of the GRUB startup screen.

Comment: Yes that would be useful, also are you able to access your linux terminal by any chance?

Comment: @Qasim ctrl+Alt+f3 is working. Terminal is quite broken, sadly.

Comment: Does the terminal allow you to input commands?

Comment: @Qasim I can open tty#. Terminal is not functional.
Picture: https://imgur.com/tnzsPcT

Comment: What happends when you choose the "advanced options for Ubuntu"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XNVZO4H @Qasim

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything that might break your system:

- [Take a full system backup!](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) (Use the [device-to-image option](https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image/06-dev-img.doc#06-dev-img.doc))
- Take a data backup
- Overwrite the existing Ubuntu Partition with another distro (which includes another or the same Ubuntu)
- If you screw up, restore the backups and try again.

OR

Go to one of your mates who has an identical system and:

- Take a data backup of your own system
- Take a system backup of theirs
- Restore their system backup
- Restore your data backup

No, seriously:

## Back up!

*If the cat walks across your keyboard while partitioning the system, and hits <kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd>, you'll have nothing left!*

Comment: I have nothing important on the Ubuntu partition, so is the backup necessary? Can it hurt the Windows partition?  .

Comment: See [the edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/518199/revisions) I just made...

Comment: I see what you say. Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 1):

*How do I remove Ubuntu (…) without effecting GRUB (…)?* – You don't.

I assume a plain setup with three partitions:

- Ubuntu (ext)
- Windows (NTFS)
- EFI System Partiion (FAT)

In this scenario, the GRUB configuration is located on your Ubuntu partition.

Just launch the installer of the Linux distribution of your choice. If it is anything like the Ubuntu installer, you are asked where to install to. Select manual or expert mode, choose your existing Ubuntu partition to be the new install's / (root) partition. Mark it for formatting explicitly (of course, you **not** want to touch the Windows partition).

[image: manual partition selection mode]
[image]
[image]

The GRUB configuration data will be lost for the time being, but the installer will re-generate it. It usually auto-detects Windows.

If you want to be on the safe side regarding "I always want to have a way to boot into Windows, no matter what might happen to GRUB", prepare a USB drive with [Super Grub2](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). If there is an operating system on your hard-drive, this nifty piece of software will make it boot.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To be completely honest, I'm afraid to preform any action because my school work is on the Windows partition and hurting it will hurt my projects. Any video to work along? And do you know if mint would work?

Comment: I do not do videos. But I added some screenshots for you. Mint would work (I personally do not recommend Mint, though. Compared to plain Ubuntu, it feels like "with additional skins and additional quirks".)

Comment: Sorry for going off-topic, which distro do you recommend? That would be able to preform this operation, of course. I'd rather not Ubuntu because I do not like the theme and the look of it, and trying to change it is what got me into that mess.

Comment: Wow!  **+1** for all the work you put into making those screenshots!

Comment: @OrOrsatti 's requested recommendation: I *like* xubuntu. I put emphasis on *like* because it is really a matter of taste. The major difference to Ubuntu is the XFCE UI, which uses a much leaner theme. Less fancy, more on-the-point. From my experience, Debian is not as easy to use; Mint comes with extra features intended to make things easier for beginners, but personally I found them less reliable.